# SignalR server side function not getting invoked

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I just started learning about SignalR and I've written a test program which takes the user input and broadcasts it.

I started off by installing SignalR library then created an Owin startup class as follows:

```
    public class Startup1
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
    }
}
```

I added a hub class for the server side functionality as follows :

```
    public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }
}
```

On the client side, the code is as follows :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            // Html encode display name and message.
            var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
            var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
            // Add the message to the page.
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
        };
        // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
        $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
        // Set initial focus to message input box.
        $('#message').focus();
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub.
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I launched the project I was getting this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

So I added the following line of code to redirect the dependencies in web.config which got rid of the error:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

The issue now is, Sending the input to the server side function doesn't work. The server side function "Send" doesn't get invoked when I click send. I don't see any errors in console log either. The compiler doesn't strike the breaking point I've set on the server side function. 
How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Usually Json.net automatically adds the proper binding redirect to your config file.
I don't think it's a problem with Json.net -- however, why do you redirect to 4.5.0.0 and not 6.0.0.0? Make sure that the version you redirect your binding to is the version you have installed using the nuget package manager.
Maybe this already resolved the issue, maybe...

Comment: The binding doesn't get added automatically when I install Json.net. From the package manager, I installed version 7.0.2 of Json but in the references the binary added shows it's version 4.5.0.0. Redirecting to any other version gives an error